# Playwright tests are running slow

Tags: c#, automated-tests, playwright

I'm in the middle of migrating our tests over from Selenium to Playwright. One of the draws to Playwright is the supposed faster run time, but I am finding that to not be the case. I wonder if I'm stepping into some kind of heffalump trap that could be easily avoided!

I created the following test to reduce the likelihood that some stupid thing I'm doing is grinding them to a halt:

```
[Test]
public async Task speed_test()
{
    playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
    browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();
    context = await browser.NewContextAsync();
    page = await context.NewPageAsync();

    await page.GotoAsync("https://www.google.co.uk/");
}
```

This test takes about 8 seconds to run headless and, as you can see, it basically does nothing. When run in parallel with 5 other tests, the run time goes up to over 30 seconds! Slower than our Selenium tests.

I know that Playwright is meant to be fast, are there some settings or something that I should look into?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Playwright will typically download the drivers needed if they aren't there when you run a test. Just to rule it out, have you checked whether or not it's just doing that _once_ rather than for every test?

Comment: Good shout. How would I check this please?

Comment: @MartinCostello this was the right answer! If you write it as an answer, I can mark it as such. You have my undying gratitude.

Comment: "When run in parallel with 5 other tests, the run time goes up to over 30 seconds!" Have you checked the CPU load on your machine when it's doing that..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playwright will typically download the drivers needed if they aren't there when you run a test.

Checked that Playwright is just doing that once rather than for every test.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try [Recording a Trace](https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer-intro#recording-a-trace)

It's hard to suggest anything concrete with the current info provided.

In general, try [recording a trace](https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer-intro#recording-a-trace) and see which operations are slow.